# If value is null then take the next higher value

Tags: functions

I have a function which requires 3 values and then uses these values to return a value from a table.

```
FUNCTION: odwh_data.annual_rental(connection_type,data_rate,date)

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION odwh_data.ead_charge_annual_rental(
    "connection_type$" character,
    "data_rate$" integer,
    "start_datetime$" timestamp without time zone)
  RETURNS numeric AS
    
SELECT  
    annual_rental
FROM    
    odwh_system.ead_credit_charge
WHERE   
    connection_type = connection_type$
AND data_rate = data_rate$
AND start_datetime$::date BETWEEN COALESCE(valid_from,start_datetime$::date) AND COALESCE(valid_to,start_datetime$::date);
```

Below is an example of the odwh_system.ead_credit_charge table:

[image]

Currently is a data_rate is passed that is not in the list is will not return an annual_rental value. I would like to update this so if the value for data_rate is 30 it will take the next higher value e.g. 100 so annual_rental of £185.00 would be returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Currently is a data_rate is passed that is not in the list is will not return an annual_rental value. I would like to update this so if the value for data_rate is 30 it will take the next higher value e.g. 100 so annual_rental of £185.00 would be returned.

Maybe you need

```
SELECT  
    annual_rental
FROM    
    odwh_system.ead_credit_charge
WHERE   
    connection_type = connection_type$
AND data_rate >= data_rate$
AND start_datetime$::date BETWEEN COALESCE(valid_from,start_datetime$::date) AND COALESCE(valid_to,start_datetime$::date)
ORDER BY data_rate LIMIT 1;
```

?

Comment: Thanks! Seems to be working.